# How to build decks with cards not present in my MTG Online collection

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

Previously in MTG Online was possible to build decks with cards not present in your collection. This is not possible any more in the latest MTG Online client.

Can someone advice on how I can build a deck with cards which I do not own, pls?

Comment: I've never tried this. Since presumably the client won't let you _play_ such a deck, is the purpose simply to help keep track of what cards you still need to obtain?

Comment: This feature is (or was?) exclusive to MTG Online, and really has nothing to do with the paper card game. Therefore, I think this question belongs on Arqade, where they have a tag specifically for MTGO, called [mtg-online](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mtg-online/info). I've flagged it so that hopefully a moderator will move it.

Comment: Our help center suggests this is on topic. Meta question: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/are-questions-specifically-about-the-computer-version-of-a-game-on-topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When viewing your collection, click the quantity button and then move the left slider to 0 to show cards you don't own. Once you see them you can just doubleclick them to add them to your deck.